# Meaning and purpose of sockaddr_ll in packet sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, network-programming

About Linux's packet sockets: in a packet socket (`AF_PACKET`), the application program implements the Ethernet header and IP header to create and send packets. So here is my question. I don't understand the necessity of socket address (`sockaddr_ll`) in this case. What is the difference from the Ethernet header? What exactly is the role of the socket address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like `sockaddr_in` identifies an IP address and port, `sockaddr_ll` indentifies a link-layer address and protocol. In the case of raw `AF_PACKET` sockets, the term "address" might be confusing, since we aren't really talking about IP/MAC or whatever other address, but we are talking about an interface (e.g. a physical network device) and a protocol.

An Ethernet header contains metadata about the Ethernet frame, and indicates which protocol ([EtherType field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType)) is being encapsulated in the payload. A `sockaddr_ll` can be used to match or to identify a certain interface and protocol (fields `.sll_ifindex` and `.sll_protocol`):

- When a packet socket is bound to a `sockaddr_ll`, it will only receive packets from the specified interface (`.sll_ifindex`) and of the specified protocol (`.sll_protocol`) determined by the kernel from the EtherType field of the Ethernet header.
- When receiving ([`recvfrom`](https://manned.org/recvfrom.2) or [`recvmsg`](https://manned.org/recvmsg.2)), a `sockaddr_ll` structure, which identifies the interface on which the packet was received and the protocol, is populated by the kernel for the user.
- When sending ([`sendto`](https://manned.org/sendto.2) or [`sendmsg`](https://manned.org/sendmsg.2)), a `sockaddr_ll` structure is used to specify on which interface to send the packet and which protocol to set in the Ethernet header (EtherType field).

---

See also this interesting article which may help understand how `AF_PACKET` sockets work: [Send an arbitrary Ethernet frame using an AF_PACKET socket in C](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/send_an_arbitrary_ethernet_frame_using_an_af_packet_socket_in_c.html).